# Do I need to update to 2.3.1?

Tags: security, magento2.3.0, magento2.3.1

If I have a store set up on 2.3 and I'm having issues getting it to update to 2.3.1 , what are the cons of not updating?

Comment: You need to check release note https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.3.1OpenSource.html to what are the cons of not updating.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give that a read